# How to automatic insert blank rows depend on 1 column?

Tags: vba, excel, blank-line

I have table same there

[image]

and I want automatic insert blank rows depend on the cell in first column, 
[image]

Anyone can help me? I tried many methods but none of it does exactly I need. 
Sorry for my English.

Comment: I have some question. When do you want to automatic add row? Like click button, Change value in first column or other.

Comment: I have a sheet and I want to automatic inserting once time - when I click button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 index column as primary key. Then insert only index column and your PK with all blank fields.

Comment: Can you describe more detail how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create button and assign to the following macro

```
Sub BRow()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Integer
    Dim lngRows As Integer
    Dim lngCols As Integer

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    FirstRow = WorkRng.Row
    lngRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    lngCols = WorkRng.Columns.Count
    WorkRng.Cells(lngRows, 1).Resize(1, lngCols).Select

    Do Until Selection.Row = FirstRow
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

See Examples [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291305)

Comment: It works, but doesn't exactly what I need. It insert blank rows but not 1 row, then is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or ... rows :D

Comment: Here is the result after run your macro [link](http://i.imgur.com/WbUxU24.png) @omar